# JavaScript - Save checkbox state shared between documents using sessionStorage

Tags: javascript, checkbox, sessionstorage

I'm trying to save the state of a checkbox using sessionStorage. I'm quite new to JavaScript so my understanding is pretty basic.

I'm using a checkbox on a website to display the navigation menu. This checkbox is present on each page of the website (same id). The aim of saving the checkbox state is to have the navigation menu already "open" when a new page is navigated to. Currently the menu "jumps" closed upon page changes and defeats the purpose of the CSS transition effect.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

This is what I've got so far (content butchered from around the web).

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkFunction(){
    var checkbox = document.getElementById("nav-btn");
    checkbox.addEventListener("onChange",OnChange,false);
}
function save(){
    var nav-btn=document.getElementById("nav-btn").value;
    sessionStorage.setItem(nav-btn);
}
window.addEventListener("load",checkFunction,false);
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="nav-btn" class="nav-btn" />
<label for="nav-btn"></label>
```

Comment: So is your problem that restoring the state does not work at all, or that there is a period after a page load where the wrong state is shown, before it 'snaps' into the correct state?

Comment: A couple of things... on the save function please camel case the nav-btn. To my knowledge i don't think javascript allows it. Second the onChange function on the checkFunction. Where is the function at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `save()` needs a couple of changes to make it work:

```
function save(){
    var navBtnVal = document.getElementById("nav-btn").value;
    sessionStorage.setItem('navBtn',navBtnVal);
}
```

As @Donte'Trumble points out in your comment, the variable `nav-btn` is incorrect syntax. That will throw an error. You can't have hyphens in variable names. I've changed the name to `navBtnVal`.

`sessionStorage.setItem()` takes 2 parameters, the first is the `key`, the second is the `value`. You were trying to set a `value` as the `key`. Even if that worked, you wouldn't be able to do anything with that later. I set it to `sessionStorage.setItem('navBtn',navBtnVal);`.

Now to access the value of `navBtn` you can simply call: `sessionStorage.navBtn`.

In your `checkFunction()` you are creating a listener for any changes to the checkbox element. Your second parameter is passing a callback of `OnChange`. We need to see the code for this function. Otherwise, I assume you were wanting to call your `save()`.

```
checkbox.addEventListener("onChange",save,false);
```

---

**Update**

I've added additional logic based on your questions in the comments. We do need additional checks. And also a couple of changes to your current code as well. I've created a [working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/enigmarm/wp79kg1j/3/).

```
//changed function name to be a bit more descriptive
//first we need to see if we have a value in sessionStorage that we should apply to the checkbox.
//Then we'll add our event listener. It should be 'change' not 'onchange'. It is passing the 'save' function as a callback.
//last we call 'toggleMenu()' to determine which state the menu should be in
function init() {
    var checkbox = document.getElementById("nav-btn");
    if (sessionStorage.navBtn == 'true') {
        checkbox.checked = true;
    } else {
        checkbox.checked = false;
    }
    checkbox.addEventListener("change", save);
    toggleMenu();
}

//this saves to sessionStorage. Note hoe I changed it to 'checked' instead of 'value'. Checked determines whether or not the checkbox is checked & returns true or false.
//last we call 'toggleMenu()' to determine which state the menu should be in
function save() {
    var navBtnVal = document.getElementById("nav-btn").checked;
    sessionStorage.setItem('navBtn', navBtnVal);
    toggleMenu();
}

//this alters the 'display' property to none or block depending on the value in sessionStorage.
function toggleMenu() {
    var navEl = document.getElementById('nav');
    if (sessionStorage.navBtn == 'false') {
        navEl.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        navEl.style.display = 'block';
    }
}
//changed to use DOMContentLoaded. This waits for the page to load before executing. 
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for all of the detailed info above, you've really cleared up a lot that I was unsure about.

Comment: Oops, accidental post (Pressed "Enter" for new line) and I exceeded the 5mins edit time. With respect to the "second parameter is passing a callback of `OnChange`. " You are correct, I meant to call `save()`. Thanks for spotting that. As you've said above to access the value of `navBtn` call: `sessionStorage.navBtn`. Should this be called within a new function and be using `if` and `else`? I'll post an example.

Comment: Something like this? Presuming that `sessionStorage.navBtn` is not literally storing checked or unchecked. Hope I'm making sense.

`function init(){
 if(sessionStorage.getItem("navBtn") === null){
  document.getElementById("nav-btn").checked = false;
 }
 else{ 
  document.getElementById("nav-btn").checked = true;
 }
}` and perhaps having `<body onload="init()">`. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I added additional logic based on your comments. I made it in to a working example and fixed a couple of other errors in the code. Everything is pretty well documented. Let me know if you have a question. Otherwise, go ahead and mark this as the answer and upvote if you found it helpful :-)

Comment: Thank you very much! I could not have asked for a better answer or explanation of each step. A little tweaking is required within my existing css, but you've provided me with more than enough to stay busy and researching for a while. Thanks again! Really appreciate all of your effort.